# finding an array of two elements in a huge 2D array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have two numbers [739 560] and I just want to know if it appears in a huge 2D array of size 9000x2

I cannot find a simple way of checking that.

Can anyone suggest anything simple? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
find(ismember(A, r, 'rows'))
```